# Win 2008 Server R2 with SQL Server 2000 memory not fully used

Tags: sql-server-2000

We have a Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise x64 with 32gb. 
We are also still using SQL Server 2000 Enterprise.

I have been monitoring the memory usage and it is only using 17.3GB total. 
I have set SQL server to use AWE with a max memory usage of 29gb.

Any ideas how to allow/get SQL server to use the extra ram?

Thanks

Comment: how much activity on the server?

Comment: 6.5gb and 4.5gb are the sizes of the 2 DB's

Comment: Their is a possibility that it does not require that amount of memory. Which would be great news for us. But I would like to verify this before assuming.

Comment: I think you have your answer. 11GB for DBs, 6.3GB for buffers, plan cache etc

Comment: @user594683
: don't forget to accept an answer if it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not using all memory is because it doesn't need it.

SQL Server is very good at managing it's own memory. The sizes of the databases you gave, fit into 11GB of RAM, that leaves 6.3 GB for internal structures such as buffers, plan cache etc. (more than enough).